# Looking for basic explanation on unity matchmaker (5.4) and how to use in scripts

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, matchmaking

Having decided to do Networking through Unity over Photon due to price (if there is a better way of networking let me know) I have been trying to create a simple unity matchmaker where when a user enters the game they first look for any other match (AKA rooms / games), if there is one they join it, if there isn't one they create one. However I am struggling to find a clear explanation of how to use the unity matchmaker, so I can develop code to get my desired behavior which seems even trickier as it seems unity is changing it's networking system a lot in recent updates so I believe anything before 5.4 is currently out-of-date. The only useful thing I have found is [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.Match.NetworkMatch.html) example code but I want to understand the system more so I don't miss any key concepts, which is likely as I am fairly beginner-ish.

So what I am asking you today is can you direct me to a clear explanation of the matchmaking system (including scripting) which is relevant to the current unity or, admittedly much harder and more time consuming, could you try to do it yourself and it will serve as future reference for others like me.

Thanks for reading, of course any answers will be greatly appreciated.

[i work in c#]

***EDIT:***

I understand my question is very difficult to answer so I am going to test out the example code until i get the desired behavior and post any errors which i cannot solve.

**Problem 1**

1. I have copied the exact code (Included below for easier reference) into a script which i have attached to my network manager. But I am getting errors due to protection levels -

[image]

I have two theories on how to solve this -

1. Changing the method accessors
2. Not deriving the script from monobehaviour

I am currently testing them out, any advice on how to solve this would be very useful. I wonder if I should report this to unity as to me it seems to be a wrong example in unity docs which say it is updated for 5.4. Thanks.

**Problem 2**

I have created this script and have run it in the editor attached to an empty GameObject with single network manager, I get no compiler errors but when I run it debugs "ERROR: Match Search Failure" which means the listmatches funtion was unsuccessful, my script is below -

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using UnityEngine.Networking.Match;
using UnityEngine.Networking.Types;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class MyMatchMaker : MonoBehaviour {
    bool done;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        NetworkManager.singleton.StartMatchMaker();
        NetworkManager.singleton.matchMaker.ListMatches(0, 20, "Match", false, 0, 1, OnMatchList);
        Debug.Log("Searching");
    }

    public virtual void OnMatchList(bool success, string extendedInfo, List<MatchInfoSnapshot> matchList)
    {
        if (success)
        {
            if (matchList.Count != 0)
            {
                Debug.Log("Matches Found");
                NetworkManager.singleton.matchMaker.JoinMatch(matchList[0].networkId, "", "", "", 0, 1, OnMatchJoined);
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("No Matches Found");
                Debug.Log("Creating Match");
                NetworkManager.singleton.matchMaker.CreateMatch("Match", 2, true, "", "", "", 0, 1, OnMatchCreate);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("ERROR : Match Search Failure");
        }
    }

    public virtual void OnMatchJoined(bool success, string extendedInfo, MatchInfo matchInfo)
    {
        if (success)
        {
            Debug.Log("Match Joined");
            MatchInfo hostInfo = matchInfo;
            NetworkManager.singleton.StartClient(hostInfo);

            OnConnect();
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("ERROR : Match Join Failure");
        }

    }

    public virtual void OnMatchCreate(bool success, string extendedInfo, MatchInfo matchInfo)
    {
        if (success)
        {
            Debug.Log("Match Created");

            MatchInfo hostInfo = matchInfo;
            NetworkServer.Listen(hostInfo, 9000);
            NetworkManager.singleton.StartHost(hostInfo);

            OnConnect();
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("ERROR : Match Create Failure");
        }
    }

    void OnConnect ()
    {
        if (Network.isServer)
        {
            Debug.Log("You are Server");
        }
        else if (Network.isClient)
        {
            Debug.Log("You are Client");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("ERROR : MatchMaking Failed, Peer type is neither Client nor Server");
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks, hopefully you may be able to see where i have gone wrong.

@Programmer

Comment: I am using unity networking 'Unity over Photon' , 'unity matchmaker' @MarcGuiselin

Comment: @MarcGuiselin Actually you got this backward. Photon replaced Unity's old networking system. Unity then released their new network system called uNet. It has matchmaker and with that there is no reason to use Photon

Comment: Hi @Programmer nice to see you again. Since our last encounter I found uNet port forwarding difficult, so tried photon and got a game working but after looking at prices I switched back to Unity but I'm struggling to understand matchmaking as above.

Comment: "but after looking at prices I switched back to Unity" lol ....I just realized we've met before. You are correct in your question. Unity is still changing their network API. It's still new and most examples won't even work in 5.4. What are specifically confused about? Is the example on their website working?

Comment: I just feel I would prefer not to dive into code without knowing much about how it works. I guess one question is what happens once you have joined a match, does that mean you are now server and client? And can get on with the game. Tomorrow I'll update this with some exact questions. @Programmer

Comment: I haven't really used Unity's matchmaking system. I have been using my own custom match system. Since you will post the complete question tomorrow, I will play with matchmaking system today.Use @ to notify me when you update the question.

Comment: Thanks I'll get back to you

Comment: @Programmer and g_l  Sorry, stupid me.  Please excuse me then.  I find the regular unity networking a bit confusing so I've moved to using photon a while ago.  So I can't help you much unfortunately.  Best of luck to you

Comment: @Programmer Done a big update now adapting script for myself

Answer (score 1):

Ah... Got this code working I debuged the information string in the call back and had to change a few project settings.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using UnityEngine.Networking.Match;
using UnityEngine.Networking.Types;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class MyMatchMaker : MonoBehaviour {
    bool done;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        NetworkManager.singleton.StartMatchMaker();
        NetworkManager.singleton.matchMaker.ListMatches(0, 20, "Match", false, 0, 1, OnMatchList);
        Debug.Log("Searching");
    }

    public virtual void OnMatchList(bool success, string extendedInfo, List<MatchInfoSnapshot> matchList)
    {
        if (success)
        {
            if (matchList.Count != 0)
            {
                Debug.Log("Matches Found");
                NetworkManager.singleton.matchMaker.JoinMatch(matchList[0].networkId, "", "", "", 0, 1, OnMatchJoined);
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("No Matches Found");
                Debug.Log("Creating Match");
                NetworkManager.singleton.matchMaker.CreateMatch("Match", 2, true, "", "", "", 0, 1, OnMatchCreate);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("ERROR : Match Search Failure");
        }
    }

    public virtual void OnMatchJoined(bool success, string extendedInfo, MatchInfo matchInfo)
    {
        if (success)
        {
            Debug.Log("Match Joined");
            MatchInfo hostInfo = matchInfo;
            NetworkManager.singleton.StartClient(hostInfo);

            OnConnect();
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("ERROR : Match Join Failure");
        }

    }

    public virtual void OnMatchCreate(bool success, string extendedInfo, MatchInfo matchInfo)
    {
        if (success)
        {
            Debug.Log("Match Created");

            MatchInfo hostInfo = matchInfo;
            NetworkServer.Listen(hostInfo, 9000);
            NetworkManager.singleton.StartHost(hostInfo);

            OnConnect();
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("ERROR : Match Create Failure");
        }
    }
}
```